# Google maps elevations

Tags: raster, google-maps, elevation

I found out that it is possible to get the elevation values for particular location, by using Google maps API:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details

What I couldn't find is the resolution of these elevation grid values?

Does Google maps use 3 arc-second (90 meters) for any other location outside of USA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro), a request will send back JSON with a **"resolution"** value.

This corresponds to the distance between the points from which this value was interpolated. According to the docs, querying multiple points in one go can reduce the resolution.

I suspect this will vary according the part of the world you're interested in. Best way to find out is to send a few queries for a single point and see what values you get for resolution...

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I actually already tried sending a query, and got the resolution up to 4 meters (grid size) for Rome, Italy.
However what makes me confused is whether or not his resolution is real, as 4 meters resolution may be raster data precision obtained through LIDAR sources.
I have been googling and it looks like Google Earth has been using SRTM 1 arc-second (30 meters) resolution for locations in USA, and 3 arc-second (90 meters) resolution for locations outside of USA.
I am wondering if Google maps actually uses this same SRTM raster data?

Comment: do yo happen to know where can I find the information on the precision of the raster data that Google maps provides? I am actually in doubt that their resolution is an actual precision of their rasters. It is impossible to have such a high precision (4 meters for example) on the global scale. I would be grateful for any kind of reply.

Comment: [check out this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/124099/55203) for some speculation/observations. Link on that answer broken, sadly, but it hints that lidar derived data may be used in patches.