# Checking Vegetation height accuracy in urban areas

Tags: remote-sensing, vegetation-index, township-range-section, data-validation

I have digitized vegetation as polygons covering the canopy of trees in urban areas. Are there any suggestions to check the accuracy of height. I have been manually validating with visual checks, comparing to google earth street view with kmz/kml, though these check are time consuming its the most reliable so far. Please advise if there are easier alternatives.

Comment: Have you assigned height based on field validation (i.e. using a Hypsometer) to all the canopy polygons?

Comment: These heights are assigned as vegetation are digitized. The vegetation was digitized manually.

Comment: If LiDAR data is available for your AOI, I would either 1) select the max point cloud return height within each polygon or 2) generate a LiDAR derived canopy height model and extract the max pixel value in each polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Earth uses SRTM DEM data as source of elevation for most part of the world ([see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124084/what-is-googles-source-for-topographic-data)). DEM is [mostly DTM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/what-is-the-difference-between-dem-dsm-and-dtm), do not considers any object over the surface. So Google Earth might not be a good source for you. I'd recommend few ideas,

- use high-res elevation data (ie. LiDAR)
- volumetric shadow analysis
- in-situ height information (ie. survey or inventory data)
- high-res SAR Interferometry

In my opinion, a carefully sampled survey data might be a better source of information.